# create multiple text files from a list using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a list of letters in a file called "letters.txt" and a list of number of occurrence of each letter in a file called "LetterPerSample.txt",both files are arranged, so first row of letters.txt has "a" second has "b"...etc, and same for SamplePerLetter.txt the first row has max nymber of "a",second has max number of "b" and so in,i want to create a list of files like this a_1,a_2,.....a_max.txt, where max is a number as listed above, and each file generated has it's own letter written inside. So a_1.txt has "a" written inside, b_5.txt has "b" written and so on

what i have done so far is:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion


for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (letters.txt) do (
    set letter=%%a
    for /f "tokens=*" %%b in (SamplePerLetter.txt) do (
    set num=%%b
    for/L %%g IN (1,1,!num!) do (
        set index=%%g
        echo !letter!>letter_labels/!letter!/!letter!!index!.lab
    )
  )
)
```

sample of the output

```
a_1.txt
a_2.txt
...
a_10.txt
b_1.txt
b_2.txt
...
b_10.txt
```

but a and b doesnt have the same number of occurrence in the file LetterPerSample.txt a has 10 and b has 5, so what's wrong with my code?

Comment: I am afraid your question is pretty confusing. Post a small example of the input files (two or three lines each) and the output you want with such input...

Comment: I have rephrased the question, hope it helps

Comment: Your question is really unclear; the description of what you're wanting to do is somewhat garbled and confusing. It's also unclear what the problem is with your code; you've not explained how it isn't working the way you want. I really can't make any sense out of *but a and b doesn't have the same number of occurrence* either. I have no idea what you're asking, even after your edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method does not require that the letters in `letters.txt` file be in order, so you may insert just the desired letters in such file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Load the number of occurrences of each letter from "LetterPerSample.txt" file
set "letters=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
set "i=0"
for /F %%b in (LetterPerSample.txt) do (
   for %%i in (!i!) do set "number[!letters:~%%i,1!]=%%b"
   set /A i+=1
)

rem Process the letters in "letters.txt" file (in any order)
for /F %%a in (letters.txt) do (
   set "letter=%%a"
   set "num=!number[%%a]!"
   for /L %%g in (1,1,!num!) do (
      set "index=%%g"
      echo !letter!>letter_labels\!letter!\!letter!_!index!.lab
   )
)
```

You may review the management of *arrays* in Batch files at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990).

If `letters.txt` file have *always* all the letters, from `a` to `z`, then this file contain redundant information that can be eliminated:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Load the number of occurrences of each letter from "LetterPerSample.txt" file
rem and create the desired files

set "letters=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
set "i=0"
for /F %%b in (LetterPerSample.txt) do (
   for %%i in (!i!) do set "letter=!letters:~%%i,1!"
   set /A i+=1
   set "num=%%b"
   for /L %%g in (1,1,!num!) do (
      set "index=%%g"
      echo !letter!>letter_labels\!letter!\!letter!_!index!.lab
   )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is, to read two files simultanioulsly. Here is a trick to do so:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
<letterpersample.txt (
  for /f %%a in (letters.txt) do (
    set /p num=
    for /l %%i in (1,1,!num!) do (
      echo %%a>letter_labels\%%a\%%a%%i.lab
    )
  )
)
```

The `for` loop (`%%a`) reads one line after the other from `letters.txt`. `set /p` reads a line from STDIN (which is redirected from `letterspersample.txt`), so if `for` reads line number 5 from one file, `set /p` reads line number 5 from the other.

(PS: I doubt, your `echo` logic is ok. Seems odd)